# Pyautogui can't be imported

Tags: python, module, importerror, pyautogui

i've been trying to import Pyautogui and here's what i'm getting :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhZ6W.png)

I tried the following :
-reinstalling the module
-uninstalling one version of python as i had two
-manually selected python debugger in VSCode where module is installed
-checked for circular import issue with other modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had old registry entries entries left here :
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python
and here :
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python

Answer (score 0):

You could add the installation of pyautogui into the path.

1. Go in options, system, system info, advanced settings
2. Click ambient variables
3. In system variables search path and click edit
4. Create a new variable and paste the path of the folder of the installation of pyautogui (it should be something like this `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts`)

Try it. It could be work.